# Conversion of NSData to int64 in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode8, int64

One of my application's DB is already written and used by other platforms.I have to save an image as int64 data type as the attribute is having int64 as the type.How can i convert image to int64 and retrieve it back from core data?Or should i convert image to NSData first and then to int64?
 This is what i tried

`[attributes setObject:sigPngData forKey:@"key"];
 [CoreDataHelper insertORUpdateRecord:@"entityName"  usingPredicate: nil withProperties: nil orderBy: nil havingDistinctResult: YES attributesToBeUpdated: attributes shouldInsertNewRecord: YES];`

Comment: What does "saving an image as int64 data type" even mean? NSData is an abstraction around a sequence of bytes; images are saved as sequences of bytes. How does int64 fit here?

Comment: @LeoNatan So can i save NSData directly to the coredata attribute which is having integer64 type?

Comment: Change the Core Data attribute to binary data. Why do you have it as int64?

Comment: I got  confused because i got this db from the same windows application.And they are using it like this.So if change it to NSData,will there be any issues while uploading to a common server?

Comment: You are designing your system. Images should generally be stored as NSData. You can then convert these datas to base64 for upload..

Comment: You need to add to your question more precise details what the DB you are talking to expects/returns. As @LeoNatan has pointed out simply saying "int64" does not provide enough information. The DB *could* store image data encoded as multiple "int64" values (which does seem improbable, but not impossible) and if so you need to know the encoding they used. "base64" is more likely than "int64", so there might be confusion here, the two are very different so you need to know which!